# What is required for direct TCP\IP connection?

Tags: network-programming

I want to write an app, that establishes direct TCP\IP connection between two devices over the internet.
I have a server to exchange IP addresses and ports, but is it enough to establish a connection?

How to handle cases, where both devices are on the one IP (connected to the same Wi-Fi hotspot)?

Also, I don't understand how open ports on the device could be accessible without port forwarding settings on hotspot? Is there any range of ports open for apps usage?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about port forwarding for most cases.

TCP/IP is [OSI Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) 4 protocol. You need to be able to send data to the sever application with a known IP address and port number. Now when on the internet, this can get more complicated because you normally do not directly interface with the IP address that the rest of the internet reaches you at. This is your public IP address. The modem you have from your ISP likely implements a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)
, which turns your private address into your public address. You modem will block all TCP SYN requests unless there is forwarding rule specifically for it.

This is just the typical case, you can also look into setting your modem up for DMZ mode and even implementing your own reverse proxy like nginx.

Comment: Great, but how does VoIP applications work? They doesn't transfer all data through server

Comment: Depends on the implementation. I believe that VOIP normally uses [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol), a layer 5 protocol. So it does not  have to use TCP, it can use any layer 3 protocol it wants. Even with TCP there are many different architectures that can be implemented, some where the phones are TCP servers, client or both. Take a look at the Open Source VOIP server [Asterisk](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Architecture%2C+The+Big+Picture) for more info.

Comment: SIP! That's the word I was looking for! Just one word, and now I know where to dig deeper! Thanks